# Google Analytics Help - 'Tracking Not Installed'?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I set up Google Analytics about 2 hours ago now [on my test website](http://www.apointlessfact.com), using the code below:

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-********-*', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

The issue however I am facing is that I am getting this error:

```
Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: Nov 17, 2014 2:17:08 PM PST
The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.
```

Using both the recommended GA Debug Extension and the Google Tag Assistant it claims that this should be working. I also checked the source (as recommended) and found that the javascript is running.

My suspicion is that this is due to the fact that I am hosting this website on [Pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) with Flask, which may be triggering errors. Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks,
Aj.

Comment: It is working, some delay in updates is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your site seems to be tracking pageview and event hits. Seeing as you just installed the GA code, you should check your Real-Time reports to see if you see any activity, like your own visits. If you see activity, then you just need to wait at least 24 hours for the data to be processed. This isn't an error at all, but it's just the way Google Analytics works.